# Can I use a beast's weapon attacks while polymorphed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, polymorph

So I'm reading over the spell as I'm progressing through DnD, and I realized you can polymorph into a Tyrannosaurus Rex if you're of 8th level or beyond. In the PHB, it says:

> The new form can be any beast whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target’s (or the target’s level, if it doesn’t have a challenge rating). The target’s game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast. It retains its alignment and personality. The creature is limited in the actions it can perform by the nature of its new form, and it can’t speak, cast spells, or take any other action that requires hands or speech. The target’s gear melds into the new form. The creature can’t activate, use, wield, or otherwise benefit from any of its equipment.

This being said, can I use the attacks that a Tyrannosaurus Rex would be able to use? It says I can't benefit from any of its equipment, but I wouldn't necessarily label attacks as equipment, although it can be features that the monster would have.  If so, does that mean I would gain:

> Bite: Melee Weapon Attack: +10 to hit, reach 10 ft., one target. Hit: (4d12 + 7) piercing damage. If the target is a Medium or smaller creature, it is grappled (escape DC 17). Until this grapple ends, the target is restrained, and the tyrannosaurus can't bite another target
>
> Tail: Melee Weapon Attack: +10 to hit, reach 10 ft., one target. Hit: (3d8 + 7) bludgeoning damage.

Tl;dr I just need confirmation on if I acquire these new attacks during a Tyrannosaurus polymorph.

Comment: Just as an aside whereas the answers below will be RAW you should check with your DM on whether dinosaurs even exist in the world within which your characters reside. I personally don't allow transmutations to things my PCs have never seen as an example.

Comment: @Slagmoth I suppose that zoos should charge druids and mages extra in such case :)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes, you can use the attacks of the new form

First, to clear up a potential misreading: the "equipment" that *polymorph* refers to is the gear of the target before it changes forms.  The gear "melds into the new form," and thus cannot be used.

As a T.Rex, your...

> game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast.

This includes the attacks available to the T.Rex.  Anything in the stat block is part of the beast's statistics.  So you can use them, as long as *polymorph* doesn't state that you can't.  The spell restricts you such that you...

> can’t speak, cast spells, or take any other action that requires hands or speech.

These attacks are none of these things (and even a claw attack arguably doesn't require hands, just clawed limbs, if the T.Rex had one available.)  As such, you may use the attacks.